# I am working on a rock, paper, scissors program using functions and it is always returning else cases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for some input on a rock, paper, scissors program that I am making where the statements in the **main()** and **determineWinner** that use **playerChoice** always terminate in the else: case. Each trial will output the player chooses scissors and that the game is tied. I am not sure where I went wrong here as I've printed the input to confirm it is correct before sending to it to the other functions. I cannot figure what pare of the above to function is causing the problem, if anyone could point me in the right direction here I would be grateful.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import random

# define main function
def main():

# initialize playAgain to start game, set stats to 0
    playAgain = 'y'
    numberTied = 0
    numberPlayerWon = 0
    numberComputerWon = 0
    print("Let's play a game of rock, paper, scissors.")

    # loop back to play again if user confirms
    while playAgain == 'y' or playAgain == 'Y':
        computerChoice = processComputerChoice()
        playerChoice = processPlayerChoice()

        # display computer choice
        if computerChoice == 1:
            print('The computer chooses rock.')
        elif computerChoice == 2:
            print('The computer chooses paper.')
        else:
            print('The computer chooses scissors.')

        # display player choice
        if playerChoice == 1:
            print('You choose rock.')
        elif playerChoice == 2:
            print('You choose paper.')
        else:
            print ('You choose scissors.')

        # assign who won to result and add total wins/ties to accumulator
        result = determineWinner(playerChoice, computerChoice)
        if result == 'computer':
            numberComputerWon += 1
        elif result == 'player':
            numberPlayerWon += 1
        else:
            numberTied += 1

        # ask player if they would like to play again
        print('')
        print
        playAgain = input('Do you want to play again? (Enter y or Y to start another game)')
        print('')

    else:
        # print accumulated wins and ties for computer and player
        print('There were', numberTied, 'tie games played.')
        print('The computer won', numberComputerWon, 'game(s).')
        print('The player won', numberPlayerWon, 'game(s).')
        print('')

# define computer choice function       
def processComputerChoice():

    # randomly select an option for the computer to play
    randomNumber = random.randint(1,3)
    print(randomNumber)
    return randomNumber

# define player choice function
def processPlayerChoice():
    choice = int(input(('What is your choice? Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors. ')))
    print (choice)

    # throw error if player makes invalid choice
    while choice != 1 and choice != 2 and choice != 3:
        print('ERROR: please input a valid choice of 1, 2, or 3')
        choice = int(input('Please enter a correct choice: '))
        return choice

# definition for the function to determine the winner
def determineWinner(playerChoice, computerChoice):

    # determine player choice and compare to computer choice to determine the winner
    if computerChoice == 1:
        if playerChoice == 2:
            print('Paper covers rock. You are victorious!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif playerChoice == 3:
            print('Rock bashes scissors. The computer is victorious!')
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again 1')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computerChoice == 2:
        if playerChoice == 1:
            print('Paper covers rock. The computer is victorious!')
            winner = 'computer'
        elif playerChoice == 3:
            print('Scissors slice paper. You are victorious!')
            winner = 'player'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again 2')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computerChoice == 3:
        if playerChoice == 1:
            print('Rock bashes scissors. You are victorious!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif playerChoice == 2:
            print('Scissors slice paper. The computer is victorious!')
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again 3')
            winner = 'tied'
            return winner

main()

input("Press Enter to continue")
```

Comment: I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement of your function `processPlayerChoice` has incorrect indentation. It should be out of while loop (unindent it one level)
At the moment, if player enters correct choice your function will return `None`.
If user enters incorrect choice, it will enter the while loop and will return whatever the second input from user is.

```
def processPlayerChoice():
    choice = int(input(('What is your choice? Enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors. ')))
    print (choice)

    # throw error if player makes invalid choice
    while choice != 1 and choice != 2 and choice != 3:
        print('ERROR: please input a valid choice of 1, 2, or 3')
        choice = int(input('Please enter a correct choice: '))
    return choice
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking at this for too long and did not realize the alignment was off. I appreciate the input. Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to align your `return` statements with the function body. Currently in both `processPlayerChoice` and `determineWinner` they are aligned with the conditional loops, and thus will not be reached every time.